# How do I install ubuntu with a disk on a dell with no operating system?

Tags: upgrade

Our 1525 insperion says it has no operating system tonight, so I'm trying to put ubuntu on it after making a disk from a download on another computer. It says "operating system not found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system. Press control+alt+delete to restart"

Comment: make sure that it's set to boot from usb in the BIOS menu.

Comment: you are not booting from the disk

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go in the BIOS and the DVD-ROM is above boot from hard drive in the list of booting priorities. <del>Also, make sure when you burn the dvd, to select the option to "make the DVD bootable".</del>

Comment: There is no such option to "make the dvd bootable".  The .iso image you download is bootable, simply burning that to a disc makes it bootable.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the image make the disk bootable right away.